# PHP & Retrospection How to retrospect without knowing class in advance

Tags: php, reflection

I want to use Retrospection to call specific functions on a class that I don't know.

I have a directory where PHP files are stored. I have another directory where my current PHP class is stored like:

```
C:/ PHP-dir
      |
      ---FilesDir
      |    |
      |    ----SomeClass.php
      |    ----OtherClass.php
      |
      ---MyProgDir
           |
           ----MyClassWithRetrospection.php
```

In MyClassWithRetrospection I read all files from FilesDir, I strip the '.php'from the filename and use the resulting string as a Class name.

So if I do a "new RetrospectionClass('SomeClass');" I get an exception telling me it can't find SomeClass in the directory where MyClassWithRetrospection is located.
Duh, I know that.

As I don't know which classes are in the FilesDir I can't do an include/required in my MyClassWithRetrospection.php file.

So does anyone know how to make the content of the FilesDir directory available at runtime?

Regards,
Werner

Comment: "Files in a directory" and "classes" are two entirely different things. It's not failing because it "can't find the class in the directory", it's failing because the file that contains the class definition has not been `include`d.

Comment: deceze, you are right. I should have explained that my class definitions are in such a way that each file represents one class with the name of the file(excluding '.php').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just include it at runtime, which means you have to follow a convention for naming your files, or you have to have a huge array of where each file is located.  Assuming SomeClass.php contains a class called SomeClass, when you do

`new RetrospectionClass($className);`

You would first do

`include_once '../FilesDir/'.$className.'.php'`

Comment: I did not know you could do that runtime. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Yes! That's the solution. Thanks Dave.